# Do Funcs of Task execute the same when using await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

If I create a `Func<Task>` and populate it with two different methods will both be executed async?

```
public async Task Execute()
{
    Func<Task> myFunc = null;
    myFunc += async () => {
        await WriteCharacters();
    };

    myFunc += () => {
        return WriteCharacters();
    };

     await myFunc();
}

static async Task WriteCharacters()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("newfile.txt"))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync("Example text as string");
    }
}
```

I have two questions about this code.  Is the First delegate added to myFunc equivalent to the second delegate added?

How are these executed, will they both be executed at the same time, or will it wait for the first to return before executing the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes* ,the following example should help.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before Execute ");
            Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("After Execute ");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

         static async Task Execute()
        {
            Func<Task> myFunc = null;
            myFunc += async () => {
                Console.WriteLine("in async func");
                await WriteCharacters();
            };

            myFunc += () => {
                Console.WriteLine("in func");
                return WriteCharacters();
            };

            await myFunc();
        }

        static async Task WriteCharacters()
        {
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("newfile.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writeing the file");
                await writer.WriteAsync("Example text as string");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*The second will start  when the first method reaches the await statement